# How to run GMS macros in CorelDraw on Mac

Tags: corel-draw

I have a macros used in CorelDraw on window but got a macbook hence i'm looking for a proper place where GMS macros should be placed?

I tried to follow the path such in the Windows
`C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Corel\CorelDRAW Graphics Suite X\Draw\GMS`,

but how to run it on Mac

Answer (score 0):

I found out CorelDraw 2019 for Mac doesnt work with VBI scripts here from GMS isn't supported and the scripting is already replaced with JS-scripts. [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CorelDRAW#:%7E:text=The%20latest%20version%20is%20marketed,was%20released%20in%20March%2C%202020.)

Comment: It's not simply Corel. VB scripts will not function on the Macintosh Operating System at all.

Comment: Whereas VBA can and does work on Mac and in Windows Draw; whether Draw on Mac has VBA support or not, I don't know.